# Specify AD username and PW SQL Server using SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer to query SQL Server databases on my Mac at home and my PC at work.

At work, I setup my connection strings and check the box that says "Use Windows Authentication" this works easy because my computer uses Active Directory(AD) to log in, and it's working seamlessly.

At home, I access the network VIA VPN on a personal computer. This computer doesn't use AD. When I try to connect to the database, I get an error saying "Login failed for user 'username'" This tells me that it's communicating with the database, but it doesn't like the parameters I'm passing for a username. I am able to Ping the server, just not connect. I think this is because I am not using active directory.

I've tried a few username varieties such as...

- domain\username
- \\domain\username
- username
- \\username
- username@domain.on.ca
- username.domain.on.ca
- subdomain\username@domain.on.ca
- domain.on.ca\username

I get the same error each time. 
I did some further troubleshooting and went back to my work computer, unchecked the "use windows authentication" box, and tried entering my username manually instead. I get the same error as I do on my personal computer.

What is the proper syntax to enter a username in manually so that it follows the same format as AD?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found this in a thread on serverfault indicating that you might need to enable TCP connections on the SQL Server to get this to work:

https://serverfault.com/a/17513